# Html fie not looking like final product

Tags: html, semantic-ui

I have this html file am working on with semantic UI,the final product is supposed to look like the one in the pic.However it doesn't render well and the image keeps being pushed to the far left side of the screen.More so the elements are also improperly aligned.Where am i growing wrong ? Here is the current code.

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv= "X-UA-Compatible" content ="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale =1.0"/>
<title>SEMANTIC UI</title>
<!--Site properties-->
<!--CSS-->
<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href ="dist/semantic.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href ="dist/mycss.css">
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dist/jquery.js"></script>

<!--Javascript-->
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dist/myjs.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<!--sidebar-->
<div class = "ui sidebar menu large compact container icon labeled vertical thin">
    <a class ="item" href ="#"><i class="global icon">Cities</i></a>
    <a class ="item" href ="#"><i class="car icon">find a ride</i></a>
    <div class = "ui buttons">
        <button class = "ui button black">
            <i class = "sign in icon"></i>Login
        </button>
        <div class = "or"></div>
        <button class = "ui button green">
            <i class = "users icon">Sign Up</a>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>

<!--Main content-->
<div class = "pusher">
    <div class = "ui vertical aligned center segment landing inverted">

        <div class = "transbg">
            <div class = "ui container">
                <div class = "ui secondary inverted top large pointing menu">
                    <div class = "left item">
                        <a class "toc item">
                            <i class ="sidebar icon"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "right-item">
                        <a class = "active item" href = "/">Home</a>
                        <a class ="item" href ="#">Cities</a>
                        <a class = "item" href="#"><i class = "car icon">Find a Ride</i></a>
                        <div class = "item">
                            <div class = "ui buttons">
                                <button class = "ui button black">
                                    <i class = "sign in icon"></i>Login
                                </button>
                                <div class = "or"><div>
                                <button class = "ui button green"><i class ="users icon"><i class = "users icon">Sign Up
                                </button>


                            </div>

                        </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "ui text container">
            <h1 class = "ui header centered inverted">Look up for a ride near you</h1>
            <div class = "container fluid findbg">
                <form class ="ui form">
                    <div class = "field">
                        <div class = "fields">
                            <div class = "eleven wide field">
                                <div class = "ui search location">
                                    <div class = "ui left icon input">
                                        <i class = "inverted circular blue map icon"></i>
                                        <input class = "prompt"type = "text" name = "location" placeholder = "enter your location...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div> 



</body>

</html>
```

[image]

CSS code file

```
.landing{
   background:url("bg.jpg") #103d50 70% 30% no-repeat !important;

 }
.landing.segment{
    min-height: 500px;
   padding:0em 0em;

 }
.transbg{
  min-height: 500px;
  background:rgba(32,154,189,0.655);

 }
.menu{
  border:0px!important;
}
.landing h1.ui.header{
  margin-top: 4.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.11em;
  font-weight: 100;

 }
 .findbg{
   padding: 1em 1.5em;
   width:100%;
   background:rgba(255,255,155,0.7);
  }
```

Comment: under the final product link after the code.

Comment: Your HTML is pretty useless without access to your includes like `dist/mycss.css`.

Comment: Not sure but seems like you have some missing closing tags for div. Also <div class = "or"><div> is not closed properly.

Comment: apologies,added the css code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say that you have a few errors in your markup:

> - unmatched closing tags (<i> is paired to </a>)
> - Misuse of Semantic UI icon tags. You shouldn't put any text inside <i class="<icon name> icon"></i> as this is
>     translated by Semantic UI to icons specified in the class attribute.
> - (As pointed out by @Anirudh) Improperly closed tag (i.e. <div class="or"> <div>)

Kindy check the code below for reference. Not sure if I achieved your desired look but it fixed the broken display in your existing markup.

```css
.landing{
   background:url("bg.jpg") #103d50 70% 30% no-repeat !important;

 }
.landing.segment{
    min-height: 500px;
   padding:0em 0em;

 }
.transbg{
  min-height: 500px;
  background:rgba(32,154,189,0.655);

 }
.menu{
  border:0px!important;
}
.landing h1.ui.header{
  margin-top: 4.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.11em;
  font-weight: 100;

 }
 .findbg{
   padding: 1em 1.5em;
   width:100%;
   background:rgba(255,255,155,0.7);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<!--sidebar-->
<div class = "ui sidebar menu large compact container icon labeled vertical thin">
    <a class ="item" href ="#"><i class="global icon"></i>Cities</a>
    <a class ="item" href ="#"><i class="car icon"></i>find a ride</a>
    <div class="item">
      <div class = "ui buttons">
          <a class = "ui button black">
              <i class = "sign in icon"></i>Login
          </a>
          <div class="or"></div>
          <a class = "ui button green">
              <i class = "users icon">Sign Up</i>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Main content-->
<div class = "pusher">
    <div class = "ui vertical aligned center segment landing inverted">
        <div class = "transbg">
            <div class = "ui container">
                <div class = "ui fluid secondary inverted top large pointing menu">
                    <a class = "toc item">
                            <i class ="sidebar icon"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class = "right menu">
                        <a class = "active item" href = "/">Home</a>
                        <a class ="item" href ="#">Cities</a>
                        <a class = "item" href="#"><i class = "car icon"></i>Find a Ride</a>
                        <div class = "item">
                            <div class = "ui buttons">
                                <a class = "ui button black">
                                    <i class = "sign in icon"></i>Login
                                </a>
                                <div class = "or"></div>
                                <a class = "ui button green"><i class = "users icon"></i>Sign Up</a>
                            </div>
                       </div> <!-- item -->
                   </div><!-- right menu-->
              </div><!-- pointing menu -->
        </div>
        <div class = "ui text container">
            <h1 class = "ui header centered inverted">Look up for a ride near you</h1>
            <div class = "container findbg">
                <form class ="ui form">
                        <div class = "fields">
                            <div class = "sixteen wide field">
                                <div class = "ui search location">
                                    <div class = "ui left icon fluid input">
                                        <i class = "inverted circular blue map icon"></i>
                                        <input class = "prompt"type = "text" name = "location" placeholder = "enter your location...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,Albert,realised i had lot of errors in my code.corrected it gives out the desired output.